# Use multiple @Observable inside each other using @Enviroment

Tags: swiftui, wwdc, observation

I'm trying the new Observation in SwiftUI 5, I created 2 classes using the new @Observable wrapper like this:

```swift
@Observable
class CategoriesViewModel {
    var categories: [Category] = []
}
```

```swift
@Observable
class NotesViewModel {
    var notes: [Note] = []
}
```

and I'm using them in the views like this:

```swift
@Environment(CategoriesViewModel.self) var categoriesViewModel
```

The question is: what if I want to use an `Observable` inside another `Observable` ?

for example, I want to use the `CategoriesViewModel` inside the `NotesViewModel`, I tried the `@State` instead of `@Enviroment` but it's not a global across all classes, so I want to use it as an environment variable like what I did in the views, I tried to use it inside the Observable class like this but I got an error below:

```swift
@Observable
class NotesViewModel {
    var notes: [Note] = []

    @ObservationIgnored
    @Environment(CategoriesViewModel.self) var categoriesViewModel: CategoriesViewModel


    func foo(){
        /// Thread 1: Fatal error: No Observable object of type CategoriesViewModel found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for CategoriesViewModel may be missing as an ancestor of this view.
        print(categoriesViewModel.categories.count)
    }
}
```

I tried to use it like the example above but I got an error

Comment: AFAIK, `@Environment` is only for use in `View` structs, not in classes, and similarly with `@State`

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine Yes, I know but I think there is a way to use the environment variable inside another obervable